# Cursor returns 0 when fetched Video content from MediaStore in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore, android-11, scoped-storage

I am trying to retrieve the Video content from MediaStore.Video in Android 11. Cursor is returning "0" with below code. I added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file and also added runtime permission check in activity before accessing below code. Can you help me how to get name, duration, size fields from all the videos in MediaStore.Video provider in Android 11.

```
    private List<MediaData> getMediaContent() {
    List<MediaData> mediaList = new ArrayList<MediaData>();
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
    };

    String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION + ">= ?";

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
            String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.HOURS))};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    try {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int duration = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION));
            int size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
            mediaList.add(new MediaData(uri, name, duration, size));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mediaList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May this helps you :

```
private final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

public Cursor getandroidPlaylistcursor(Context context) {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    final String id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID;
    final String name = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME;
    final String[] columns = { id, name };
    return  resolver.query(uri, columns, null, null,name + " ASC");
}
```

But if you use Mefiaplayer :

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(uriOfYourFile));
 int duration = mp.getDuration();
etc(...)
```